# ArrayFormula to Validate and set array against a validation array

Tags: google-sheets

Thanks for taking the time to look at my question.

I’m struggling to find the right combination or arrayformula, vlookup, index/match pairing. My goal is to test each cell of a 1 column data array (type string) against a validation set of single or paired words in another 1 column array. If the cell in the data array contains a validation word then the function enters the validation word into the adjacent cell in the data array, If no match is found then the adjacent cell should be set to null. For testing my function I’m using data something like the following.

```
       Desc_Array                         Result Array Validation_Array

     | A                                 |     B      |    C     |
   __________________________________________________________________
1    | Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet        |  (null)    | Quis nisi|
2    | Consectetur adipiscing elit       |  Cons      |   Ut     |
3    | Sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt  |  Sed       |   Et     |
4    | Ut labore et dolore magna aliqua  |  Ut        |   Ad     |
5    | Ut enim ad minim veniam           |  Ut        |   Cons   |
6    | Quis nostrud exercitation ullamco |  (null)    |   Sed    |
7    | Laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea     |  Ut        |          |
8    | commodo consequat                 |  Cons      |          |
```

The arrayformula function would be in cell B1

A few things to note in the results array.
The test is TRUE if the validation word appears at the beginning of any word in the data array.
The test can return TRUE on finding the first match.
The test is not case sensitive

For the test, could I use a simple regexmatch expression?

```
=if(Desc_Array<>"",regexmatch(Desc_Array,"\A(?i)"&Validation_Array),(NOT(ISBLANK(Desc_Array))))
```

I tried a QUERY “contains” method but it fails test 1.

I think I’m after something like:

```
=ArrayFormula(iferror(index(Validation_Array,match(Validation_Array,Desc_Array,FALSE),1),))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",",1,ArrayFormula(IFERROR(
REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A8,
"(?i)[^a-z\-]("&JOIN(")|[^a-z\-](",C1:C6)&")|^("&JOIN("|",C1:C6)&")"),
"(null)"))),","))`

Notes:

`C1:C6` = Validation_Array

`A1:A8` = Desc_Array

Comment: Much appreciated Max. Not only would my skills have prevented me from reaching your solution but it's also going to take me awhile to unpick your expression to see how it works. The reason is that although your Result_Array is close, it actually uses the source format and not the validation format - which is something I omitted to specify. I'm going to investigate further to see if I can remove that as an issue.

Comment: To get the original format, you need to add extra functions: `= ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(my_formula, Validation_Array, 1,), "(null)"))`. I did not want to include this in A, because it complicates the formula.